# processing a cube take more time in visual studio than in processing through SQL job

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

I built a cube and the processing takes much time if i process the cube from visual studio. But the same cube is processed faster through scheduled job. In VS it take 2 hrs to process but through sql job it takes 1 hr. both the process are done in the same server. Is there is any settings i need to change in VS IDE or it has anything to do with the hardware e.g. increasing the ram or change any buffer size in visual studio

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you need to factor in.

1) Visual Studio runs in 32bit, SQL Server most likely in 64bit. On the top of my head I am not sure if this is a factor in SSAS projects, but it definetely is an aspect (and a pain) in SSIS packages.

2) Visual Studio needs to render the progress window and write the progress into the logfile (and display it, too) the SQL Server doesn't, which also affects the processing speed. I experience an improvement of roughly 20-25% between Visual Studio and running the job in the SQL Server.

Generally I wouldn't worry about the VS performance, as long as the job runs with sufficient speed in the SQL Server.

Comment: for me it takes double the time... 30 mins become 60 mins.  My Visual Studio is on another server in the same network, the VS server also only has half of the RAM